# sbt unresolved library dependencies

Tags: scala, sbt

sbt compile issues unresolved dependencies error

Research SBT configuration.  I do have the correct syntax.  But SBT still issues error

```
name := "MyProject"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

resolvers += 
  "Sonatype OSS Snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases"

libraryDependencies += "java.io.IOException" % "IOException" % "latest.integration"

libraryDependencies += "java.io.FileReader" % "FileReader" % "latest.integration"

libraryDependencies += "java.io.FileNotFoundExceptiom" % "FileNotFoundException" % "latest.integration"
```

I have a working scala program.  I expect the dependencies to be included instead I receive the following Warning.  What am I missing?
Warning Message

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: java.io.IOException#IOException;latest.integration: not found
[warn]  :: java.io.FileReader#FileReader;latest.integration: not found
[warn]  :: java.io.FileNotFoundExceptiom#FileNotFoundException;latest.integration: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Comment: Those seems like standar java classes... you don't need to include them as dependencies, they are always present in a **JRE**. Also the dependencies are intended to be external projects _(usually in form of **JARs**)_, not single classes. If you comment/remove that lines from your project do it works as expected? or do you have any error in compile-time/runtime?

Comment: Yes it does.  Thank you for clarifying the differences.

Answer (score 1):

hmm, there's something weird.

Typically you declare dependencies in a form of a lib/jar that does contain a set of classes, and not the individual class itself.

In your specific case, you don't even need to add any dependency to get java.io.* classes since it belong to standard library and are included by default